# Randomise youtube link to play in an embedded video

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#video").attr('src', idea(ads));
$(".heading").text(idea(ads));
var ads = ["https://youtu.be/nSZtxXNjmLA", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2pOkm4opVU"]; 
function idea(el) {
    return el[Math.floor(Math.random() * el.length)];
}
```

So I am using the function idea to randomise it. The iframe has an id of video.

Comment: You are calling a function before it's defined.

Comment: @SilverRingvee Functions are hoisted to the top of the scope.  Try running this in your console for example: `a('x');function a(p) {console.log(p);}`

Comment: What isn't defined though is the value of `ads` - the variable itself is defined, but the array isn't assigned.  @Rahul, can you confirm what error you're actually seeing?

Comment: Uncaught reference error. $ Not defined

Answer (score 0):

1 - Move `var ads` to the first line

2 - Link jquery in yout html https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
```

```js
var ads = [
  "youtu.be/nSZtxXNjmLA",
  "youtube.com/watch?v=D2pOkm4opVU",
  "youtu.be/WElPhX5Pb6I",
  "youtu.be/78mNZeDaMtk"
];

$("#video").attr('src', idea(ads));

$(".heading").text(idea(ads)); 

function idea(el) { 
  return el[Math.floor(Math.random() * el.length)]; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="heading"></h1>
  <video src=""></video>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: var ads = ["https://youtu.be/nSZtxXNjmLA", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2pOkm4opVU", "https://youtu.be/WElPhX5Pb6I", "https://youtu.be/78mNZeDaMtk"];

$("#video").attr('src', idea(ads));
$(".heading").text(idea(ads));

function idea(el) {
    return el[Math.floor(Math.random() * el.length)];
}

Now I am doing this. But there is no error. And still now working.